# fetching data from column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to fetch only that row which have column (name-time,and type timestamp) greater than certain Timestamp and less than certain timestamp... I used this code written below but it is giving me error .. I want know is it right sql syntax or not

```
<?php
include_once'header.php';
$time=$_GET['t'];
$prev=$_GET['prev'];
$q="SELECT * FROM comment WHERE time<'$time' AND time >'$prev' ";
$r=mysql_query($q);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
echo "<p>".$row[4]."</p>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(taken from http://www.php.net/manual)

```
    $firstname = 'fred'; $lastname  = 'fox';

    // Formulate Query 
    // This is the best way to perform a SQL query 
    // For more examples, see mysql_real_escape_string() 
    $query = sprintf("SELECT firstname, lastname, address, age FROM friends WHERE firstname='%s' AND lastname='%s'",
        mysql_real_escape_string($firstname),
        mysql_real_escape_string($lastname));

    // Perform Query $result = mysql_query($query);

    // Use result
    // Attempting to print $result won't allow access to information in the resource
    // One of the mysql result functions must be used
    // See also mysql_result(), mysql_fetch_array(), mysql_fetch_row(), etc.
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['firstname'];
        echo $row['lastname'];
        echo $row['address'];
        echo $row['age'];
    }
```

The point here is, you shouldn't use unescaped expressions in your query, as they can provide a means to SQL injection.

Also, in your particular query, you can use the sql keyword BETWEEN:

```
$q=sprintf("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE time BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'",
   mysql_real_escape_string($prev),
   mysql_real_escape_string($time));
```

Also note that mysql_query is deprecated, try to use mysqli_query instead.

Answer (score 0):

did you make connection with mysql

```
$conn = New mysqli(SERVER, USER, PASS, NAME);
if (!$conn)
{
die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE time<'".$time."' AND time >'".$prev."' ");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<p>".$row[4]."</p>";
echo "<br>";
}
```